# What are the requirements to be shown in the battlelog leaderboard?

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

Recently I've been viewing the leaderboards and I saw that [this guy](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/soldier/farhad_rus/stats/778604518/) has the highest **K/D Ratio**(***64.76***). But then I've found [another guy](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/soldier/Stationary-AA/stats/513908734/) whose ratio is even better(***477.25!!!***).

So I've got that question: what are the requirements to get to the leaderboards? Do you have to have a minimum of some amount of deaths or do they just ignore people with some crazy stats?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get to the leaderboards'?

Comment: Both of those example accounts seem to have some odd stats. Both have around the same time played, but the service stars are very different. I'm not sure how farhad_rus can be a 145 rank Colonel with only one service star. Or how Stationary-AA has the Javelin at the top weapon at 36 kills. Maybe they reset their stats at some point?

Comment: @Meraj99 the question is: why is that "Stationary-AA" not first(or at least not above fahrad) in the leaderboards

Comment: @DanielBallinger that's true. However is you take a look at fahrad_rus's vehicle stats you will see that he used T90 MBT a lot. Tho' he only has 1 tank service medal(10 hours in a tank). The Stationary-AA guy is mostly using stationary AA's. That's probably how they got these odd stats.

Answer (score 1):

Every player is featured on the leader boards by default. Your position is obviously dependent on your stats for a particular category. As far as I know, there is no way of checking your overall ranking on Battlelog (without browsing through countless pages).

You can head over to [BF3 Stats](http://bf3stats.com/) to check which percentile you fall into for general game play stats (SPM, KD Ratio, etc) as well as other areas including weapon usage, vehicle usage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you need 100 deaths to get your K/D on the K/D leader boards. I reset my stats on BF3 and they would only let my new K/D show when I did reach a certain mark.
Everything else should show up automatically on the leader boards.